# Si plusieurs adjectifs modifient un nom, doivent-ils être rangés dans un certain ordre ?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, syntaxe

En anglais, si plusieurs adjectifs modifient un nom, on doit les ranger dans un certain ordre. Par exemple, on dit :

> - She bought some *good porcelain* vases while she was on vacation.
> - He is eating a *pink, Swedish* cake.

Cependant, ces constructions ne sont pas admissibles :

> - She bought some *porcelain good* vases while she was on vacation.
> - He is eating a *Swedish, pink* cake.

[Voilà](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) une explication de cet aspect de la grammaire anglaise. Il faut noter que l'ordre des adjectifs n'est pas complètement fixé. Ce site web donne l'exemple de "a round, Italian, bread-like Christmas cake" comme exemple d'une expression qui se conforme à ces restrictions syntaxiques, mais je peux dire aussi "a round, bread-like, Italian Christmas cake."

Y a-t-il en français des restrictions similaires sur l'ordre des adjectifs?

Comment: Certains adjectifs doivent se mettre avant le nom (ceux comme beau, grand, etc) mais s'il y a plusieurs, je ne sais pas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comme l'indique la longueur de [l'article Wikipedia correspondant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l%27adjectif_en_fran%C3%A7ais) c'est un sujet *très* complexe. Pour le dire en quelques mots, plusieurs tentatives ont été faites pour identifier les règles de sériation (pour employer des mots barbares), au moins pour quelques sous-classes d'adjectifs, mais elles restent assez limitées et peu généralisables.

[Denis Bouchard](http://rlv.revues.org/1383) a proposé en 2005 une revue de littérature assez intéressante que je t'encourage à lire et dont voici (une partie de) la conclusion (c'est moi qui souligne)

> **La sériation des adjectifs est très semblable d’une langue à l’autre**, non
>   pas en terme d’ordre absolu, mais plutôt de distance relativement au nom.
>   **Cette sériation n’est pas absolument rigide**, mais apparaît comme une
>   tendance qui est reliée à la propension qu’ont les humains à créer des
>   Concepts. L’adjectif le plus près du nom est celui qui permet le plus
>   naturellement de construire un Concept avec le nom. […]
>
> **L’emboîtement des adjectifs dans la sériation correspond à un emboîtement de Concepts, de classes que l’on forme : plus la classe est naturelle, plus immédiatement l’adjectif est combiné avec le nom**. Quand la tendance pour une sériation est très forte, comme Provenance qui est plus près du nom que Taille, mon analyse dit que c’est parce qu’il est plus naturel pour le système cognitif des humains de former la classe Provenance + Nom que la classe Taille+ Nom.
>   **Il reste à vérifier s’il y a vraiment une telle hiérarchie quant au naturel
>   des Concepts, et sur quelle base elle repose. Mais cela dépasse le cadre d’une étude en linguistique.**

Et plus haut dans l'article

> l’adjectif dont la sémantique se prête le mieux à une modification directe du nom tend à se retrouver plus près de ce dernier.  La question de fond est donc de déterminer en quel sens un adjectif modifie plus directement le nom qu’un autre adjectif.

Concernant l'exemple de *porcelain*, en revanche, je ne suis pas très convaincu : il ne s'agit pas là d'un adjectif mais d'un nom employé comme modifieur (qui serait d'ailleurs traduit en français par un groupe prépositionnel), il n'est donc pas très surprenant qu'il n'ait pas le même comportement qu'un adjectif. Sans avoir vraiment poussé la recherche sur cette question (puisque ce n'est pas le sujet ici, voir plutôt [en.se](http://english.stackexchange.com)), il me semble qu'en anglais, les noms modifieurs suivent toujours les adjectifs épithètes.

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour *porcelain* et je pense que c'est le même cas que *Christmas* dans l'exemple avec le gâteau italien.

Answer (score 3):

I have come up with three example phrases to illustrate the point of consecutive adjectives.

Essentially, the more intrinsic (the stronger) the relationship between an adjective and a noun, the closer they are to each other.

---

> 1. une connexion | **neuronale** | **active**
>
>    = {an active neural connection}

In the first example, the adjective "neuronale" is more strongly linked than the adjective  "active" to the noun "connexion". Which is why the "neuronale" immdiately follows the "connexion".

---

> 2. **le seul** | **prétendu** | témoin | **oculaire**  |  **sobre**
>
>    = {the only supposedly/so-called sober eyewitness}

The same goes for the noun "témoin" and the adjective "oculaire" in the second example; they are inseparable first and foremost. The "le seul" precedes everything else.

Then the adjective "prétendu" always comes immediately before a noun. And the adjective "sobre" that corresponds to the "prétendu" needs to come last.

---

> 3. **une des plus populaires** | recettes de plats | **traditionnels** | **japonais**
>
>    = {one of the most popular traditional Japanese recipes}

In the third example, the phrase "un/une des plus ..." comes first. Contrary to how it works in English, the adjective "japonais/français" is placed farther away than the adjective "traditionnels".

Comment: "Une des plus populaires recettes de plats traditionnels japonais" is not very idiomatic, I would say "(l')une des recettes de plats traditionnels japonais les plus populaires"

Comment: @jlliagre The rationale for the word order that I chose in the 3rd example is: I divided the entire phrase into two parts: "une des plus populaires recettes" and "de plats traditionnels japonais". And I meant the latter part as a kind of afterthought, so to speak. Though it is not exactly an afterthought. Merci.

Comment: @jlliagre It is like "one of the most popular recipes (of traditional Japanese cuisine)". Merci.

Comment: That's "une des plus populaires recettes" which isn't idiomatic. That would work with "une des plus belles recettes" but "plus populaire recette" hurts French ears.

Comment: @jlliagre Oh, j'y vois clair maintenant. Si j'emploie "belles" à la place, la troisième phrase laisse rien à désirer tel qu'il est ? Merci.

Comment: Oui, la troisième phrase **ne** laisse rien à désirer **telle qu'elle est**.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks for a couple of additional points, too!

Comment: "une des recettes de plats traditionnels japonnais les plus populaires" is all right but a formulation that would put the essential idea across  more pungently is "une des recettes les plus populaires de plats traditionnels japonnais".